# Improve nested IF and CHOOSE formulas

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I receive weekly statuses for our open work orders as a CSV file.  This includes 3-letter status codes associated with different steps in the completion process.

I need to put the plain-language definitions in place of the status codes.

My spreadsheet does this automatically, but the spreadsheet I feel like how I'm doing it right now is really inefficient.  The sheet that does this, by itself, is over 75 MB, and bogs the whole thing down.

How my current sheet works is a 16-column grid that with the status codes from the CSV at [@[SO Codes] and a static list of the codes at Row 1.  Each other row is 16-across with:

`=IF([@[SO Codes]]=Table3[[#Headers],[AA]],1,0)`
`=IF([@[SO Codes]]=Table3[[#Headers],[CA]],2,0)`
`=IF([@[SO Codes]]=Table3[[#Headers],[CAN]],3,0)`
etc

So each status code gets assigned a number from 1 to 16 that shows up on the 16x[the number of work orders open] grid.

The last column of is:

`=SUBTOTAL(9,E2:T2)`
`=SUBTOTAL(9,E3:T3)`
`=SUBTOTAL(9,E4:T4)`
etc

Finally, that feeds into my tracker with lines that look like:
`=CHOOSE([@Status],IF([@Status]=J2,L2),IF([@Status]=J3,L3),IF([@Status]=J4,L4),IF([@Status]=J5,L5),IF([@Status]=J6,L6),IF([@Status]=J7,L7),IF([@Status]=J8,L8),IF([@Status]=J9,L9),IF([@Status]=J10,L10),IF([@Status]=J11,L11),IF([@Status]=J12,L12),IF([@Status]=J13,L13),IF([@Status]=J14,L14),IF([@Status]=J15,L15),IF([@Status]=J16,L16),IF([@Status]=J17,L17))`

Where column L is the list of plaintext code definitions, and J3 feeds off the subtotals from the status code calculator.

I can't help that there has to be a more elegant and efficient way of doing this.  Any insight?  I tried using the =CHOOSE function directly on the codes from the CSV, but it only works on numeric values.  I've included pictures of each step, because I feel like I've explained this poorly.

CSV Code Calculator
[image]

Tracker
[image]

Comment: Sum is faster than subtotal (9,  ... Vlookup is faster than =IF([@[SO Codes]]=Table3[[#Headers],[AA]],1,0)  ... but do you have years of data closed that is hidden in smart filter?    why so big?  =Vlookup(text cell, array with Code in 1st column, 2 ( if Description in 2nd column),0=exact match)

Answer (score 1):

That Choose formula could be written as

```
=Vlookup([@Status],$J$2:$L$17,3,False)
```

Not sure I understand what the rest of the problem is.

Comment: two Vlookups, possible Code Descriptions and Status

Answer (score 0):

### code calculator:

Instead of the long table you can use a single `MATCH()`:
`=MATCH([@[SO CODES]],TableHelper[code list],0)`
[image]

### Tracker

Here I'm not sure I understand your original formula correctly.

`=CHOOSE([@Status],IF([@Status]=J2,L2),IF([@Status]=J3,L3)...` - What happens if `[@Status]<>J2`? Or is that an unrealistic scenario? If yes, then just use a simple `INDEX()` function:
`=INDEX($L$2:$L$17,[@Status])`

Otherwise please specify what your formula should do.

### Ultimate optimization:

Again, if you understand your issue well: you don't even need the double sheets, just one.

> I tried using the =CHOOSE function directly on the codes from the CSV, but it only works on numeric values

Indeed, you can feed the codes directly, just use `VLOOKUP()`, something like this:
`=VLOOKUP(<code>,$J:$K,2,false)`

Where

- `<code>` is a code for which you want to get the description
- `$J:$K` are code and description columns according to your screenshot

Comment: Thanks for all the answers!  It is clear that I need to learn how to use =vlookup.  I am new to Excel.  Anyway, the first table converts a 3 letter status code into a number.  The second table looks at what the number is, and then returns the corresponding plain language description for the status code.  This whole system is a lot more convoluted and resource-intensive than it needs to be.  You guys really helped me out.  Thanks!